# Error while running "gulp"

Tags: ionic-framework, gulp, node-sass

I have an ionic application which I am trying to run on browser using "gulp" command but it's giving me an error, regarding the directory that error:

> File to import not found or unreadable: www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic. which is shown below in an image:-

[image: The version of node I am using is 5.12.0 and npm is 3.8.6]

Answer (score -1):

There's a problem with your sass files, the way you're including it. Or probably the file doesn't exist.